# Non-connected polygons not selectable and disappearing after merging in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge

I have to digitalize the zoning plan of a village. After I copied all zones in my layer and classified them by giving them a usage type (industrial or residential zone etc.) a problem occurred with merging them. The goal is to have one polygon for every usage type containing all areas of this type in the village.

In my layer, I do have now multiple connected and also non-connected polygons with the same usage type. I want to merge all polygons with the same type into one polygon.

As long as the polygons are connected to each other there is no problem and I can just use the merge tool from the advanced digitization toolbar.

When I want to merge non-connected polygons there is a problem that after merging them the new polygon is only selectable and zoomable from one specific point (one polygon from before the merge) and when zooming in on any other point it keeps disappearing.

Normally, merged polygons behave like one new polygon. In this case the polygons are merged but the new polygon still behaves like one of the small polygons. It seems like one polygon takes all the attributes but the others still get merged to it.

Does somebody know what the problem is and/or how to fix it?

---

Examples:

This is how I merge the polygons:
[image: How i merge the area]

It's only possible to select the whole polygon in one specific polygon:
[image: selecting not possible]

Zooming is also only possible on this specific polygon:
[image: zooming not possible]

When I zoom to the object it also only shows the specific polygon:
[image: only showing specific polygon]

Comment: You are probably corrupting the geometries by merging in an edit session. Have you tried doing a dissolve by attribute?